# Is it possible to use RegionFunction with Graphics3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am using Graphics3D and I would like to use `RegionFunction` to exclude specific regions as in `Plot3D` but I could not. Here is my code:

```
ax := 0; az := 1; ay := 0
unitCell3D[x_, y_, z_] := {Black, Sphere[{x + ax, y + ay, az}, 0.13], 
Black, Sphere[{x + ax, y + ay + 2/3 Sin[120 Degree], az}, 0.13], 
Gray, Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax, 
y + ay + 2/3 Sin[120 Degree], az}}, 0.02], 
Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax + Cos[30 Degree]/2, 
y + ay - Sin[30 Degree]/2, az}}, 0.02], 
Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax - Cos[30 Degree]/2, 
y + ay - Sin[30 Degree]/2, az}}, 0.02]}

f2 = Graphics3D[
Block[{unitVectA = {Cos[120 Degree], Sin[120 Degree], 0}, 
unitVectB = {1, 0, 0}}, 
Table[unitCell3D @@ (unitVectA j + unitVectB k), {j, 20}, {k, 
20}]], PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 7.128}, {1.3, 8.0}, {-0.3, 1.3}}, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]  
p2 = Plot3D[1, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z}, 
3 <= (x - (-0.1 + 7.128)/2)^2 + (y - (8 + 1.3)/2)^2 <= 50], 
Axes -> None, MeshStyle -> None, PlotPoints -> 80, 
PlotStyle -> 
Directive[Red, Specularity[White, 10], Opacity[0.9], 
Lighting -> "Neutral"], BoundaryStyle -> {Green, Thick, Dashed}]

Show[f2, p2, PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 7.128}, {1.3, 8.0}, {-0.3, 1.3}}, 
Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {3, -6, 3}]
```

[image]

inside the dashed-green circle is an excluded region in the `Plot3D`, but results from `Graphis3D` are showing within this excluded region. I tried to use `RegionFunction` in the `Graphis3D` but it did not work. I would like exclude this region in both figures, is that possible?

Comment: The output of `Plot3D` and other `3D`-rountines is a `Graphics3D` object. You can merge arbitrary `Graphics3D` objects with `Show`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, when I combine them using `Show`, the excluded region in `Plot3D`appears in the `Graphics3D` plot

Comment: Hm. Not when I try it. Please give an example, then we can see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, well, I think I did not made the point clear. Simply,  in the first fig with Hexagonal lattice, I would like to exclude a  specific region (inside or outside a circle on the top one) as explained in the last two Figs. So the last two figures are just to imply what I would like to do with the first one. Combining them using `Show`will not exclude the desired region in the hexagonal lattice plot

Comment: Ah. Then you should make that clear in the post itself, not only in a comment.

Comment: Henrik Schumacher, question is edited, I hope it clear now-:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach using [`DiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) and [`RegionDifference`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDifference.html) to manually cut the affected objects:

```
hole=Cylinder[(* the object describing the hole to cut out *)
   {
    {(-0.1+7.128)/2,(8+1.3)/2,0},
    {(-0.1+7.128)/2,(8+1.3)/2,2}},

   ];

dhole=DiscretizeRegion@hole(* discretized version of hole *);
f2/.
  Sphere->Ball/.(* replace Sphere with Ball to ensure all the objects are solid *)
  (* replace all regions that intersect with the hole *)
  r_?(RegionQ@#&&!RegionDisjoint[hole,#]&):>
   If[
    RegionWithin[hole,r],(* if the region is fully contained, drop it *)
    Nothing,
    (* otherwise cut out the part intersecting the hole *)
    {
     EdgeForm@None,(* this ensures that the cell edges are not drawn *)
     BoundaryMesh[(* we only care about the surface *)
      RegionDifference[DiscretizeRegion@r,dhole](* discretize and cut away the hole *)
     ]
    }
   ]
```

[image]

The objects at the boundary of the hole are properly handled:

[image]

Comment: may you pleas show me how can I do the opposite, I mean remove outside the sphere and leave the inside. I tried [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225518/discretizeregion-is-not-working-properly-with-graphics3d?noredirect=1#comment574031_225518) but did not work nicely