# DiscretizeRegion is not working properly with Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I have a 3D object and I would like to remove everywhere except a part with a circle shape. Here is the 3D object

```
ax := 0; az := 2; ay := 0; rs = 0.1; rl = 0.01;
unitCell3D[x_, y_, z_] := {Black, Sphere[{x + ax, y + ay, az}, rs], 
   Black, Sphere[{x + ax, y + ay + 2/3 Sin[120 Degree], az}, rs], 
   Black, Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax, 
      y + ay + 2/3 Sin[120 Degree], az}}, rl], Black, 
   Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax + Cos[30 Degree]/2, 
      y + ay - Sin[30 Degree]/2, az}}, rl], Black, 
   Cylinder[{{x + ax, y + ay, az}, {x + ax - Cos[30 Degree]/2, 
      y + ay - Sin[30 Degree]/2, az}}, rl]};
xUns[j_] = j Sin[\[Pi]/3] + 0.1;
f2 = Graphics3D[
  Block[{unitVectA = {Cos[120 Degree], Sin[120 Degree], 0}, 
    unitVectB = {1, 0, 0}}, 
   Table[unitCell3D @@ (unitVectA j + unitVectB k), {k, -10, 
     10}, {j, -10, 10}]], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Method -> {"EdgeDepthOffset" -> False}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5.6, 5.6}, {xUns[-6] - Sin[\[Pi]/6], 
     xUns[6]}, {-0.3, 2.3}}]
```

and here is how I remove the desired part

```
hole = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -3}, {0, 0, 2}}, Sqrt[10]];
dhole = DiscretizeRegion@hole; g2 =
 f2 /. Sphere -> Ball /. 
  r_?(RegionQ@# && ! RegionWithin[hole, #] &) :> 
   If[RegionDisjoint[hole, r], Nothing, {EdgeForm@None,
     BoundaryMesh[RegionDifference[DiscretizeRegion@r, dhole]]}];

Show[g2, Graphics3D[hole], Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Top, 
 ImageSize -> 450]
```

but some dangling lines and dots exist in the removed region, see below. How can I make it perfectly removed outside the circle?

[image]

Comment: What for you build this region?

Comment: I would like to remove everywhere except the defined circle

Comment: How do you use it - just for plotting or in some problems with FEM?

Comment: @AlexTrounev for plotting

Comment: You need to change `RegionDifference` to `RegionIntersection` - after all, you want to include the part of the structure that is intersecting the cylinder here instead of cutting away the cylinder. The other change required is that you should make the upper limit of `hole` larger, e.g. `3` (otherwise you're cutting your structure in half, which will take way longer, and is probably not what you want)

Comment: Thanks, @LukasLang! that does the trick